# How to optimize usage of extremely low API daily limits

Tags: algorithm, optimization, query-optimization, rate-limiting

I’m using the term “post” below. For clarity it’s very much similar to news articles or blog posts. My script looks for keywords and phrases within the text (or title) of each post.

I’m using an API that has a limit of 1000 requests per day. I query the API to receive a list of recent posts within a date range. The list of posts I receive in the response only has basic information like title, date posted, author and post ID but not the actual text of the post. For that I need to send another API request to get the text for that single post. Now here’s the catch - this website averages ~1,500 posts per day.

So far I’ve implemented a search of the title before making the 2nd API call. If a keyword or phrase is found in the title I can skip the 2nd call for post text and move onto searching the next post, saving a few calls each time the script runs but still not nearly enough for days when there is 3,000+ posts.

Problems:

- Limited to 1000 API calls per day
- Website averages 1,500 new posts per day
- The API is designed so that each post requires two calls to get the data we’re looking for
- 1st call – List of recent posts
- 2nd call – Data for a specific post

Has anybody encountered a similar problem with API daily limits not being enough to cover a full day’s worth of data? Is this just a poorly designed API I’m using?

Comment: Are you paying to use the API?

Comment: @user3386109 No, it's a free API but you need to be registered as a specific kind of business to have access.

Answer (score 0):

Why 2 calls for each post. 1st call lists recent post**s**, no? I quote:

> I query the API to receive a list of recent posts within a date range. The list of posts I receive in the response only has basic information like title, date posted, author and post ID but not the actual text of the post.

So, say you make one call per hour to the recent-posts api, then you would need `total number of posts - total number of posts with keyword in title + 24` api calls per day.

Depending on the frequency of requests you send to the recent-posts api, its number can be considered negligible compared to the rest. Say, we ignore 24 for an hourly check. Then you are left with the following: Are there more than 1000 posts per day where you need to check the text? If so, there is no way around it other than buying a better api package if available. And the number of posts that you need to look at the text is, as said before, `Nr. of total posts in a given period - Nr. of posts with keywords in title in the same interval`.